# Should I strictly follow restful guidelines

Tags: design, web-development, rest

I have the following resources in my Asp.net web API:

route: consisting of the following relevant properties

- arrival_location_id
- leaving_location_id

and location:

- id
- name
- coordinates

The thing is, When I create a new route, I create many routes and I want to allow users to create a new locations if they don't already exist.

I have two different approaches that I can think of

### Create an action that manages both

I would recieve something like the following json

```
{
       "routes":[
           { 
               "arrivalLocationId": 1,
               "leavingLocationId": -1
           },
           { 
               "arrivalLocationId": -1,
               "leavingLocationId": 2
           },
           { 
               "arrivalLocationId": -2,
               "leavingLocationId": 2
           }
           ],
        "locations":[
                { /*blablabla*/}
                { /*blablabla*/}
            ]
    }
```

The action will insert the locations, and than update the negative ids to the right id of each location.

### Create two different actions

The other option is the more restful one, It requires two different calls to the server - first insert the new locations, and than insert the routes.

#### Pros and Cons

The first requires less calls to the Server, and therefore reduces data usage.

The last is more restful, and much more simplistic in terms of development - no need for different checks in the server side, probably easier also for the client side.

I assume that in my case it doesn't matter that much, but these kind of things create sort of a guideline for future developers, and it might make a difference in the future -

so the real question is -

should lowering data usage be a big factor in my API design or only when the difference is noticable?

Comment: Short answer: Favour simplicity until you need performance. Other than that, guidelines are guidelines.

Comment: also consider whether you want the new locations and the route to be added atomically in a single transaction

Comment: There isn't anything non-RESTful about the first option. Go with that. REST is concerned with transfer of state of resources between client and server, not the form the resources take. If you want a resource that has both routes and locations as part of its data format, go for it.